# Issue with QTextEdit, QPushButton one works with QMainWindow and the other with QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Is there something in the QMainWindow class that won't allow to properly place a QPushButton where I want it to be?

Here the QPushButton "Quit" is at the wrong place and a little too big than usual.

[image]

My code is

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication , QPushButton, QToolTip, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QAction,
QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont

class QQtWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        btn = QPushButton("Quit", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close) 
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(btn)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Test") 
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
f = DemoQt()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

If I make the class inherit from QWidget instead of QMainWindow the PushButton will be properly placed, but I can't use some other function if I inherit from QWidget.

Another Issue is with the QTextEdit module. It seems I cannot edit anything

[image]

in it if I use this code

```
class OpenSavePath(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
"I realise here that this might be the problem as there is no 
setCentralWidget() module in QWidget"""
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        save_btn = QPushButton("Save", self)
        save_btn.clicked.connect(self.saveCSV)

    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addStretch(1)
    hbox.addWidget(save_btn)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addStretch(1)
    vbox.addLayout(hbox)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 250)
    self.setWindowTitle("Rocket Packet Preview")
```

Notice here the QPushbutton that is also misplaced. By changing the parent class QWidget with QMainWindow and adding this following line

```
self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
```

The text editor issue is gone and I can edit. But then my QPushButton appears. Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem: You must use `QSpacerItem` to place it in a corner.

Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem, QPushButton

import sys

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        spacerItem = QSpacerItem(20, 10, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        vbox.addItem(spacerItem)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        spacerItem1 = QSpacerItem(10, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        hbox.addItem(spacerItem1)
        btn = QPushButton("Quit", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close)
        hbox.addWidget(btn)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle("Rocket Packet Preview")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

For this second problem: You must use `QSpacerItem`, `QVBoxLayout`, `QHBoxLayout` to organize the items. `QMainWindow` have loaded default widget like `QStatusBar`, `QDockWidget`, etc. So the `setCentralWidget()` function is used to place the main widget.

Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QTextEdit, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton
import sys

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        spacerItem = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        hbox.addItem(spacerItem)
        save_btn = QPushButton("Save", self)
        hbox.addWidget(save_btn)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle("Rocket Packet Preview")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. Also I am curious as to why you sometimes add self for example

    `vbox = QVboxLayout(self)`

But did not include self in 

    `hbox = QHLayout()`

Also what is the "Widget" in `super(Widget, self)`?

Comment: `layout={layout class}({parent})` is similar to `{parent}.setLayout(layout)`

Comment: When you inherit, you must initialize what the father does. `super(class.__name__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I'm still new so there are some things I need to learn.